# How can i achieve a complicated flink pattern from single stream to multiple and then join back to single stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My question is how will you achieve flink streaming based on the picture below ...
here are the steps

1. I get streams in kafka (each msg in the stream has an id)...
2. I process the streams in a process function
3. Based on the process i sub divide the streams into multiple streams, but these streams are dynamic.. Meaning that for first msg in kafka i could process and produce 3 streams .. which needs to be joined .. for second message i produce 2 streams .. which will be joined... the common joining factor is the id for each message.
4. Then after joining each and producing a single result i need to sink it .

How can i achieve that? Any help would be appreciated.

Now i could do that with just a single process and sink it .. but I want to use the full capability of flink streaming and make my code very modular.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The topology of the job graph has to be determined at compile time. You can't dynamically create new streams at runtime.

The building blocks you want to investigate are *side outputs* for splitting a stream, and *union* and *(Keyed)CoProcessFunctions* for merging streams.